# Queue with Threading, peculiar result

Tags: python, queue, python-multithreading

If i remove the line with time.sleep, the printed result is 3 otherwise it prints 1. Why is that?

````
for i in [3,2,1]:
    def f():
        time.sleep(i)
        q.put(i)
    threading.Thread(target=f).start()
    
print(q.get()) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

This could be interpreted as a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition. Execution order of work in threads isn't guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Threading starts the targeted code in another thread, meaning a Race condition might occur.
in this example the race condition appears to be that the print function is called before the loop fully finished.
I added this to your code to explain myself:

```
for i in [3, 2, 1]:
    def f():
        print(f"added {i} {time.time()}")
        q.put(i)


    threading.Thread(target=f).start()


print(f"{q.get()} {time.time()}")
```

The result was:

```
added 3 1665115594.661886
added 2 1665115594.6622424
added 1 1665115594.6624556
2 1665115594.662505
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no evidence of a race condition.  It is true that the execution order of the threads is not guaranteed, but the time intervals you are dealing with here are so long that the code is virtually deterministic.

A threaded program gives the appearance of running several blocks of code in parallel; this is achieved by rapidly switching from one thread to another.  The switching time is much less than one second.  In your case, when one thread sleeps the others can run.  If they are all sleeping, or waiting on a queue, nothing will happen until one of the sleeps times out.

In the version with the time.sleep() line included, your program does this:

- Starts a thread with an index of 3.  Before placing an item in the queue, this thread delays for 3 seconds.
- Starts a thread with an index of 2.  Before placing an item in the queue, this thread delays for 2 seconds.
- Starts a thread with an index of 1.  Before placing an item in the queue, this thread delays for 1 second.
- The main thread waits for the first item in the queue, prints it out, and exits.  The thread with an index of 1 is the first to write to the queue (it sleeps for the shortest amount of time).  Therefore the main program prints the message from that thread.  Nothing else can possibly happen.

In the version without the sleeps, the thread with an index of 3 is the first one to start.  It is not surprising that it is also the first one to write something to the queue.  It seems to me that this result is not necessarily guaranteed, since the switching from one thread to another is dependent on an internal mechanism in the environment, probably involving the operating system.  But you do not observe this in your case, so there is nothing peculiar about the behavior of this little script.

Comment: There *is* a race condition, but not where you're looking. `i` is looked up each time it's used, not when the functions are defined. Depending on thread scheduling, a thread may see the value of `i` that existed when the thread was started, or a value from a later iteration of the loop. With different thread scheduling, the no-sleep version might print `1` 3 times.

Comment: With the sleeps, if the loop rebinds `i` before a thread looks up `i` for `time.sleep(i)`, the thread might sleep for the wrong duration, but barring an unusually massive delay in the main thread, by the time a thread executes `q.put(i)`, `i` will be `1`. (`i` will be `1` for `q.put(i)` in *all* the threads, not just the thread that was supposed to put `1`.)

Comment: @user2357112 I see now that you're absolutely correct.  Thanks for the insights and clear explanation.